# Retrofit error while getting boolean with false value

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm working with retrofit 2.0 using OkHttp3 as network layer. Retrofit getting error while web server sending boolean data with false value,
here is example of web service json 
`{"login":false}` Retrofit error while load data with this json.
but retrofit works well with boolean with true value, like this
`{"login":true,"data":{"id":6,"name":"xxxx ","email":"xxxx@xxxx.com"}}`

here is error message

`retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request`

Comment: What is the error ? Edit the question with that

Answer (score 0):

The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.

The request is incorrect so retrofit is giving you an error, the server is not sending you a response because its not understanding what the question is.

Comment: but the device/android has successfully recieved the json, here is the json that the android received {"login":false} but still there is error while parsing the json